# data is not binding to array in angular4 typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have event coming in using socket.io and pushed it to array object, Now i see its being added to array but its not updating or binding to the view if click on that component then i see it gets updated , Do we have something like `ng-blur` options in angular 4 so we can achieve this task ?

`secondConfigObject.data` is datasource of data grid i am using.

stream.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.socket.on('newMessage', (newEvent) => {
            console.log('New Event', newEvent);
             this.sortArray(newEvent);
        });
}

sortArray(newEvent){
  var streamArray = this.secondConfigObject.data;
streamArray.push(Object.assign({},newEvent.data));

}
```

Comment: You have bad history of marking answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can manually trigger using **`ChangeDetectorRef`**

```
constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

sortArray(newEvent){
  var streamArray = this.secondConfigObject.data;
  streamArray.push(Object.assign({},newEvent.data));
  this.cdr.detectChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: `detectChanges()` saves my life once per week

Comment: and i thought i was the Angular master....did not even know that smth like `ChangeDetectorRef` existed....thank you very much. +1

Comment: so that resolved partial issue when i have new event that got inserted but when i update existing event that is not updating i have to click outside of the grid

Comment: Do i need to do something like this ` this.secondConfigObject.data = [..streamArray]` before i execute  `detectChanges()`

Comment: whatever changes you need make sure you have it before detectchanges